# Cross domain req in AngularJS using the $http.Get? reverse Proxy and JSONP

Tags: xml, angularjs, eclipse, web-services, cors

Well i'm being confused!!
Some says to do a Cross Domain, Some others Bypass Proxy, some others recommand to use JSONP...What is the right solution?

Here's my situation:

I'm running my webservices on Apache (Eclipse) and my front is on IIS server (Visual Studio) and I need to communicate with the both servers. 
Using in AngularJS using the $http.Get I want to call my web service and retrieve data. But I have the CORS origin failed.

- I tried to add the header `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`  to my return web service like that :

  ```
   @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  public Response convertCtoF() {   
          Double fahrenheit;
          Double celsius = 36.8;
          fahrenheit = ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
          String test = "[{'data':'balala'}]";
          return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").entity(test).build();
      }
  ```

and It only works with JSONP. the **JSONP** method with an ajax call it works but only with ***json webservices*** and i can't get it work with **xml** returns.

- For the reverse proxy I don't know how to configure it on Eclipse!!

Can anyone help .?

Comment: possible duplicate of [REST API with JSON representations using Apache CXF without Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175370/rest-api-with-json-representations-using-apache-cxf-without-spring)